# BringToFront on User Control slows down over time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application with panels and user controls (not many, maybe 5 or so), that has a workflow/step-based wizard for a user to complete. When a user completes the steps and finishes on the last screen, a `ResetForm` function is called that sets some variables to default and calls a function within the form called `ShowControl(Nothing)` (hiding only the panels) and then re-initializes to the start of the workflow by calling `ShowControl(uctInitial)`. `ShowControl` is in the main form.

```
Private Sub ShowControl(control As Control, Optional message As String = "")
        If pnlField.Visible And pnlField IsNot control Then pnlField.Visible = False
        If pnlHistory.Visible And pnlHistory IsNot control Then pnlHistory.Visible = False
        If uctAutoAsk.Visible And uctAutoWeigh IsNot control Then uctAutoAsk.Visible = False
        If uctConfirm.Visible And uctConfirm IsNot control Then uctConfirm.Visible = False
        If uctInitial.Visible And uctInitial IsNot control Then uctInitial.Visible = False

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
            lblFilter.Text = message

            pnlFilter.Visible = True
            pnlFilter.BringToFront()
        End If

        If control IsNot Nothing Then
            control.Visible = True
            control.BringToFront()
        End If
End Sub
```

We have found that after a few hours / day or so, `control.BringToFront()` starts running slower and slower. On a fresh start of the Windows Application, it refreshes within a few hundred milliseconds, after some time, the `control.BringToFront()` starts taking a second, then two, and eventually up to 30 seconds (I ran logging in parts of the function to determine where exactly it slows down)

The form is also refreshed on a "time out" schedule as well, so if there's no user interaction (a user starts the process but never completes it) the `ResetForm` function is called

I can't find any reason why this would appear to slow down or build up / slow down after a period of time, especially when there's no user interaction (the application runs 24/7)

All I know for sure is, that when `ShowControl(uctInitial)` is called, and `BringToFront` is called for that control, that it gets slower and slower and eventually appears to "hang" the program. Memory usage sits at 59mb consistently but CPU spikes to 35% on the `ShowControl(uctInitial)` call, and the longer it has to wait, eventually shows in task manager that the program isn't responding.

When a user starts interacting with the form, `ShowControl` is used to show/hide other User Controls, and doesn't appear as slow or taking time to `BringToFront`

We have a previous version of this without the `DisplaySignIn` running perfectly fine.

EDIT: `uctInitial.SetupOptions` and `uctInitial.SetSize` is called each time `ResetForm` is called before `ShowControl`

Here's the code for `uctInitial`

```
Public Class uctInitial

    Public Property DisplayMSR As Boolean
    Public Property DisplayTag As Boolean
    Public Property DisplaySignIn As Boolean
    Public Property DisplayPin As Boolean
    Public Property DisplayCasual As Boolean

    Private _statusExtended As Boolean = False
   
    Public Sub SetupOptions(ByVal msr As Boolean, ByVal userTag As Boolean, ByVal pin As Boolean, ByVal casual As Boolean, ByVal signin As Boolean)
        DisplayMSR = msr
        DisplayTag = userTag
        DisplayPin = pin
        DisplaySignIn = signin        
        DisplayCasual = casual        

        ArrangePage()
    End Sub

    Const marg As Integer = 50
    Const leftmarg As Integer = 30
    Public Sub ArrangePage()

        If pnlInitial.Visible Then
            Dim screenW As Integer = Me.Width
           
            lblSignIn.Left = (screenW - lblSignIn.Width) / 2

            pnlSignInOptions.Top = lblSignIn.Bottom + marg
            pnlSignInOptions.Left = (screenW - pnlSignInOptions.Width) / 2 - 5

            DisplayUserOptions()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayUserOptions()
        Dim itemCount = GetItemCount()
        Dim orIndex = 0
        Dim leftPosition = GetStartPosition(itemCount)
        Dim orAdded = False
        Dim addedItem = False
        
        If DisplayMSR Then
            Dim btnToAdd = GenerateButton("btnMSR", "with a stripe card", Resources.icon_swipe_card, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(btnToAdd)
            leftPosition = btnToAdd.Left + btnToAdd.Width
            addedItem = True
        End If
        
        Dim isOrRequired = addedItem AndAlso (DisplayTag Or DisplaySignIn Or DisplayPin Or DisplayCasual)
        If isOrRequired Then
            orIndex = orIndex + 1
            Dim labelToadd = GetORLabel(orIndex, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(labelToadd)
            leftPosition = labelToadd.Left + labelToadd.Width
            orAdded = True
            addedItem = False
        End If
        
        If DisplayTag Then
            Dim btnToAdd = GenerateButton("btnDallasTag", "with a dallas tag", Resources.Resources.icon_dallas_key, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(btnToAdd)
            leftPosition = btnToAdd.Left + btnToAdd.Width
            orAdded = False
            addedItem = True
        End If
        'OR
        isOrRequired = addedItem AndAlso (DisplaySignIn Or DisplayPin Or DisplayCasual)
        If orAdded = False AndAlso isOrRequired Then
            orIndex = orIndex + 1
            Dim labelToadd = GetORLabel(orIndex, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(labelToadd)
            leftPosition = labelToadd.Left + labelToadd.Width
            orAdded = True
            addedItem = False
        End If
        
        If DisplaySignIn Then
            Dim btnToAdd = GenerateButton("btnSignIn", "with your email credentials", Resources.icon_swipe_card, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(btnToAdd)
            leftPosition = btnToAdd.Left + btnToAdd.Width
            orAdded = False
            addedItem = True
        End If
        'OR
        isOrRequired = addedItem AndAlso (DisplayPin Or DisplayCasual)
        If orAdded = False AndAlso isOrRequired Then
            orIndex = orIndex + 1
            Dim labelToadd = GetORLabel(orIndex, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(labelToadd)
            leftPosition = labelToadd.Left + labelToadd.Width
            orAdded = True
            addedItem = False
        End If
        'CASUAL
        If DisplayCasual Then
            Dim btnToAdd = GenerateButton("btnCasual", "as a casual", Resources.icon_casual_vehicle, leftPosition)
            AddHandler btnToAdd.Click, AddressOf cmdCasual_Click
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(btnToAdd)
            leftPosition = btnToAdd.Left + btnToAdd.Width
            orAdded = False
            addedItem = True
        End If
        'OR
        isOrRequired = addedItem AndAlso DisplayPin
        If orAdded = False AndAlso isOrRequired Then
            orIndex = orIndex + 1
            Dim labelToadd = GetORLabel(orIndex, leftPosition)
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(labelToadd)
            leftPosition = labelToadd.Left + labelToadd.Width
            orAdded = True
        End If
        'PIN
        If DisplayPin Then
            Dim btnToAdd = GenerateButton("btnPin", "with your pin", Resources.icon_pin_pad, leftPosition)
            AddHandler btnToAdd.Click, AddressOf cmdPin_Click
            pnlSignInOptions.Controls.Add(btnToAdd)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetStartPosition(itemCount As Integer) As Integer
        Select Case itemCount
            Case 1
                Return 420
            Case 2
                Return 330
            Case 3
                Return 220
            Case 4
                Return 110
            Case 5
                Return 5
            Case Else
                Return 2
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Function GetItemCount() As Integer
        Dim items As Integer = 0
        If DisplayMSR Then items += 1
        If DisplayTag Then items += 1
        If DisplayPin Then items += 1
        If DisplayCasual Then items += 1
        If DisplaySignIn Then items += 1
        Return items
    End Function

    Private Function GetORLabel(id As Integer, position As Integer) As Label
        Dim lb As Label = New Label()
        lb.AutoSize = True
        lb.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24.0!, CType((FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic), FontStyle), GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        lb.ForeColor = Color.White
        lb.Name = $"lblOr{id}"
        lb.Size = New Size(20, 20)
        lb.Text = "or"
        lb.Location = New Point(position - 6, 100)
        Return lb
    End Function

    Private Function GenerateButton(name As String, text As String, image As Bitmap, position As Integer) As Button
        Dim button As Button = New Button()
        button.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        button.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
        button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(16, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer))
        button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(16, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer))
        button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        button.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18.0!, CType((FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic), FontStyle))
        button.ForeColor = Color.White
        button.Image = image
        button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
        button.Location = New Point(position, 41)
        button.Margin = New Padding(0)
        button.Name = name
        button.Size = New Size(168, 270)
        button.Text = text
        button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
        Return button
    End Function


    Public Event PinClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub cmdPin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles btnPin.Click
        RaiseEvent PinClick(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Public Event CasualClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Private Sub cmdCasual_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles btnCasual.Click
        RaiseEvent CasualClick(sender, e)
    End Sub    

    Public Sub SetSize(ByVal h As Integer, w As Integer)
        Me.Height = h
        Me.Width = w
        ArrangePage()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any advice as to why this is running slower over time would be highly appreciated. I'm busy banging my head against a wall trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: We can only see Controls.Add() calls, when do they get disposed?  Use Task Manager, add the "USER objects" column.   A steadily increasing number spells doom

Comment: `DisplayUserOptions` creates and adds controls. If it is called repeatedly, this might actually be the reason for the slow-down.

Comment: You're saying: *uctInitial.SetupOptions and uctInitial.SetSize is called each time ResetForm is called*. Both these methods, `uctInitial.SetupOptions()` and `uctInitial.SetSize()` then call `ArrangePage()` which the calls `DisplayUserOptions()`. `SetupOptions()` has parameter, but it's not clear what arguments are passed to the method. `SetSize()` doesn't, so it appears it's counting on previous settings, whatever these are. Also not clear why `ArrangePage()` should be called twice. If this actually end up creating new (overlapping) Controls each time, see the ending in the first comment.

Comment: @HansPassant Currently I don't think they're being disposed (nothing in the inherited code-base suggests it does). I'm assuming you mean Task Manager in VS.NET because I don't get that option on Windows Task Manager. Will check

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It might explain the slow-down, but we have a version that is live currently that doesn't experience the same slowness, so that's why it's confusing. I will see if I can refactor

Comment: @Jimi Apologies for being unclear, SetupOptions takes boolean parameters to show/hide a button that has a picture on it for people to click/touch on. SetSize takes the Form Height and Width each time

Comment: `SetupOptions()`, each time it's called, ends up calling `ArrangePage()`, which calls  `DisplayUserOptions()`: with the booleans set to `true`, it **creates** new Controls each time. So does `SetSize()`. If you call both `SetupOptions()` and `SetSize()` each time `ResetForm()` is called (or even just one of these methods), you create a host of Controls (possibly containing Graphic objects) that you never dispose. That's the end of any application, not just in WinForms.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, busy refactoring now and testing. What is strange is that there are live versions with this running perfectly. I'm trying to find out from Ops how frequently some machines are rebooted or the application is restarted. Definitely worth a refactor in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to the commenters on my question. It always helps to have more than 2 eyes on a problem and this helped me a lot.

By using `FindControl` before just adding the control whenever `uctInitial` was called to "refresh", I was able to remediate the issue and not add 10 objects EACH TIME.

A big help was Windows Task Manager to show my client what was happening; Task Manager -> Details tab -> Right-click on the column headings -> Select Columns -> Tick User Objects

Thanks again to the commenters for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You can accept your own answer to mark the problem as resolved.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks, it said I needed to wait 24 hours before accepting my own answer :)